# Delphi xe2 , can't import Field of type varchar from mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, odbc, delphi-xe2

I just Create a connection to my Database ( MYSQL ) Using ODBC witch use The mysql API  and i start using Tdatabase   Component and Ttable Component and Datasource and Dbgrid and i notice that Fields of  Types like ( Varchar and LongVarchar and text . ect )

the Ttable Component  can't import  Those type of mysql  they just import the basic numeric types like ( int and float ect ) but how can i get values like string .

thak you .. sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved 
1 TSQLQUERY , and this is the one that i insert SQL filters.
1 DATASETPROVIDER connected to the TSQLQUERY.
1 CLIENTDATASET connected to the DATASETPROVIDER.
Now its the same as ACCESS DB's, 1 DBGRID connected to a TDataset, and that TDataset is connected to the previous CLIENTDATASET.